# How to verify in-app purchase receipt when user change device or uninstall app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am new to iOS programming and new to in-app purchase.
I am using auto renewal subscription in my app, in which after successful subscription I am verifying receipt through which I update my server for services, so basically my problem is that is user uninstall app or change device then if I restore transaction or refresh receipt it prompt for app store credentials, by this I got the receipt but I don't want to do that instead I want to verify receipt without prompt. So, is there any way to verify receipt?

NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];

If  am using this it gives nil on new app installation, also let me know if I send receiptURL data to my server and through which how can I rewrite that data to [NSBundle mainBundle] on new device or new installation.

Also I am using RMStore library.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's really only one work-around for this.  You link the purchase to a user account on your system and store the purchase date.  When they launch your app you know if their subscription is active or not.  If it's not active in your system then you need to prompt them to renew.

Otherwise there is no way to do this without querying iTunes, which requires them to authenticate.

It's very common, many of the apps I use require me to "validate purchases" from time to time.

Comment: I am using auto renewal subscription and if my app prompt for renew again and again then degrades user experience because why app ask for renew again if there is already auto renew subscription.